# print all maximum values using awk

Tags: linux, awk, max

I'm trying to print all maximum values

so, if the text looks like

'''

name1 job1 9500.
name2 job2 9500.
name3 job3 4500.

'''

I want to print it like

'''

```
job: job1, sal: 9500
job: job2, sal: 9500
```

''''

so far, my code is

'''

```
     BEGIN {a=0}

     {if ($3> a)
     max=$3;
     output=$2
        }

  END{
    print "job: ", output, "sal:", max}
```

'''

and the output I'm getting is

'''

```
job: job2, sal: 9500
```

'''

Comment: Please format your code clearly when asking other people to read it to help you. Run `gawk -o-` on it if you don't know how to do that.

Comment: please update the question to include the (wrong) output generated by your code; also consider reviewing your code in detail ... 1) it looks like you're tracking the max value with 2 different variables (`a` and `max`) ... 2) the `print` command is generating something different (4 tokens per line) from what you've said should be in the expected output (2 tokens per line)

Comment: is the input already sorted by the 3rd column in descending order (as displayed in your sample input)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way might be keeping track of the maximum number, and if you have a number that is higher then store that number.

If it is the same amount as the current number, then keep track of those lines (field 2 and field 3) in an array, and at the end print them.

```
awk '
{
  if ($3 > max) {
    max = $3
    i = 0;
    lines[++i] = $2 OFS $3
    next;
    }
  if ($3 == max) lines[++i] = $2 OFS $3
}
END {
  for (j=1;j<=i; j++) print lines[j]
}' file
```

Output

```
job1 9500
job2 9500
```

Comment: thank you for the answer! But I'm trying to print it like                                                              job: job1 sal: 9500.                                                                                                                          job: job2 sal: 9500.                                                                                                                        Your code works fine when I try to just print field 2,3. But it doesn't work when I try to print it like what I want

Comment: @wannabe In that case you can write the desired format as `lines[++i] = "job: " $2 OFS ", sal: " $3`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an awk two pass solution so the entire file does not need to be in memory:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{max=$3>max ? $3 : max; next}
$3==max {print $2, $3}' file file
```

Prints:

```
job1 9500
job2 9500
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need 2-pass, and don't need to pre-fit it ***all*** in memory :

```
echo "${input}" | gsort -n | gtee  >( gpaste - >&2; ) | 

mawk '+_ <= +(__=$3) { if (+_<+__) { 
                         split("",___)
                         _ = __ 
                      ____ = NR 
                     }   ___[NR] = $2 OFS __ 
  } END {   
          for (_=____;_<=NR;_++) { if (_ in ___) { 
                   
              print ___[_] } } } ' | gcat -n | ecp

name1 job1 9500.
name2 job2 9500.
name3 job3 4500.
 
     1  job1 9500.
     2  job2 9500.
```

> 

```
echo "${input}" | gsort -nr | gtee  >( gpaste - >&2; ) | 

gawk '+_ <= +(__=$3) { if (+_<+__) { 
                           split("",___)
                             _ = __ 
                     } ___[NR] = $2 OFS __ 
      } END { 
              PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"

              for (_ in ___) { 
                       
                  print ___[_] } } ' | gcat -n | ecp

name3 job3 4500.
name2 job2 9500.
name1 job1 9500.
 
     1  job2 9500.
     2  job1 9500.
```

Because when you need only the ones matching the maximum value, simply store up the rows that match your current max,

so whenever a new max is found, all previously stored rows are no longer eligible, so simply clear the entire array (`split("", arr)`) and start fresh, while updating the state variable noting what's the current line number (`NR`), so you wouldn't need to loop all the way from 1

If the input also contains negative values, then set the initial state of `"_"` to `log(0) aka neg. infinity`

> - note difference between `mawk` and `gawk` versions of the code